# Dynamic Mobile Swipe Content

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, dynamic, swipe

Hello all I am designing a mobile website and am pretty inexperienced in mobile jQuery, so if you can all be kind enough to help me out. If I could get his part of the page to refresh when you swipe. This div contains a product catalog code within  so that the products change when ever you refresh the page. What I would like to be able to do is have one specific div tag in my page to refresh upon making a swiping motion.

```
<div data-role="content" id="colorme">

<!-- Start:Here is where the product come up-->
<!--START: ITEM_TEMPLATE_0-->
<div style="padding: 1em .5em 1.5em .5em; text-align:center;" id="bg" >
    <div style="background-color:#ffffff; margin-bottom: .5em;"> <a href="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]"><img src= "/thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]&maxx=200&maxy=0" width="200" alt="[name]" border="0"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:.5em;" class="name"> [name]
    </div>
    <div>
    <a href="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]"><img src="images/btn-more-details.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END: ITEM_TEMPLATE_0-->
<!-- END: stop products-->

  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>My Footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a bunch!

Sorry, you can view the website here:

kitchenova.com/mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the jQuery Mobile library, you can use `swipe()`

http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

This is an event listener which will detect a "swipe" event (I use the quotes because it technically listens for a click and drag, not a native touch event)

You can place whatever function you need within this, to accomplish whatever you are attempting.

If all you need is for new content to be brought into the div, you can also just implement something like a swipe carousel using a variety of different plugins (Many of which will actually use real touch events, which can be tricky to do on your own, but will work much better and be much smoother than jQuery's swipe method)

I'd recommend swipejs:

http://swipejs.com